# Javascript: Call function inside Node.js object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, express, asynchronous

I want to call this asynchronous callback function:

```
var glob = require('glob');
var globResults = undefined;
function globAsync(callback) {
  glob('*.jpg', { cwd: 'public/portfolio/weddings/', sort: true }, function (err, files) {
    var results = JSON.stringify(files);
    globResults = results;
    callback();
  });
};

function globCaller() {
  var g = globResults;
  console.log('STRING: ' + g);
  return g;
};
globAsync(globCaller); // This will init globCaller()
```

Inside this Node.js router:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('portfolio', {
    layout: 'main',
    centering: true,
    titleShown: false,
    title: 'Hi!',
    description: 'Home page of Lantos Istvan Photography',
    keywords: 'wedding,photography,film,lantos,istvan',
    bodyClass: 'horizontal',
    imagesFolder: '\/portfolio\/weddings\/',
    images: globCaller()
  });
});
```

I want this expected output placed after `images:` in the upper example (this is show in the console):

```
["image-1.jpg","image-10.jpg","image-11.jpg","image-12.jpg"]
```

How can I do this?

I also have this handlebar file:

```
  {{#each images}}
  <li><img src="{{../imagesFolder}}{{this}}.jpg" alt=""></li>
  {{else}}
  <p class="empty">No content</p>
  {{/each}}
```

Sometimes the rendered output in the html output is:

```
<li><img src="/portfolio/weddings/image-1.jpg,image-10.jpg,image-11.jpg,..." alt="" /></li>
```

But I want:

```
<li><img src="/portfolio/weddings/image-1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="/portfolio/weddings/image-10.jpg" alt="" /></li>
<li><img src="/portfolio/weddings/image-11.jpg" alt="" /></li>
```

Comment: Is the `globAsync` in a different module?

Comment: I followed the tutorial here to get the asynchronous callback's result outside of itself: https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node#callbacks I'm new to JS.

Comment: You should make `globResults` a parameter of the `globCaller` (and an argument of the `callback` call).

Comment: `… images: globCaller() …` makes no sense.

Comment: If you want an array, why do you pass the results through `JSON.stringify()`? Just remove that line.

Comment: @Bergi Can you provide an example code for this in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler just to have res.render() in glob()'s callback instead of having all the global variables:

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    glob('*.jpg', { cwd: 'public/portfolio/weddings/', sort: true }, function (err, files) {
        var results = JSON.stringify(files);

        res.render('portfolio', {
            layout: 'main',
            centering: true,
            titleShown: false,
            title: 'Hi!',
            description: 'Home page of Lantos Istvan Photography',
            keywords: 'wedding,photography,film,lantos,istvan',
            bodyClass: 'horizontal',
            imagesFolder: '\/portfolio\/weddings\/',
            images: results
        });

    });
});
```

**EDIT: Alternative solution as discussed in comment**

```
function globAsync(params, callback) {
    glob(params.wildcard || '*.jpg', {
        cwd: params.cwd || 'public/portfolio/weddings/',
        sort: true
    }, function(err, files) {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        // Do anything else with the results (files) if you need to here

        callback(null, files);  // null means no error, return results in callback
    });
}

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    globAsync({
        wildcard: '*.jpg',   // use default in globAsync if not passed in
        cwd: 'public/portfolio/weddings/' // use default in globAsync if not passed in
    }, function(err, results) {
        if (err) {
            return res.send(err);
        }
        res.render('portfolio', {
            layout: 'main',
            centering: true,
            titleShown: false,
            title: 'Hi!',
            description: 'Home page of Lantos Istvan Photography',
            keywords: 'wedding,photography,film,lantos,istvan',
            bodyClass: 'horizontal',
            imagesFolder: '\/portfolio\/weddings\/',
            images: results
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, working! Really there's no way to define in a global variable? Placing the entire router inside a function feels not right. As @Juhana said, I had to remove `JSON.stringify()` also.

Comment: Yes, you can define the call separately and call it too using callback.  I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thank You! Works perfectly!